# How should I explain why I wish to reapply to an apprenticeship

Tags: applications

I am doing an apprenticeship as a software developer that will be due by may.

Over the 3 years I've been doing this apprenticeship, I constantly grew unhappier because of the lack of an actual trainer and actual software developing tasks.

I would like to reapply for an apprenticeship at a different company. My letter of application should point out the fact that I already have 3 years of experience in the field (due to self-education mostly), yet I would like to avoid a grumbling undertone.

Note: I learned pretty much about web dev, but everything else that I should have been taught is missing. I would fail every recruitement test for sure. That's why I want to apply for a new apprenticeship not a 'regular job'.

How should I clarify my motives without any ranting?

Comment: You've been doing the same apprenticeships at the same company for the past three years? Or is it one apprenticeship for the entire three years? Did you ask for software development tasks, or were you waiting for them to be assigned to you? Because if you didn't tell them a thing about what you can do, they may have decided they couldn't delegate anything to you based on what they knew about your capabilities, which you didn't tell them anything about - they are not mind readers.

Comment: When you complete the apprenticeship in May are you supposed to receive some certification from the company/mentor?

Comment: once you have done the apprenticeship your done with that stage of training the next step varies advance or professional apprenticeship or sponsored for a degree are the next obvious steps

Answer (score 5):

After three years as an apprentice, chances are **you have outgrown apprentice positions**. A new apprenticeship will likely be similar to your current experience. There may be many things you do not know but no one knows everything.

**Apply for junior developer positions**. You may get rejected a few times or not do great on tests but so do other developers. Focus on any weaknesses so you will do better in the next interview.

> How should I clarify my motives without any ranting?

Say something like "The apprenticeship was a great experience but I am now looking for something more challenging" or "After my time at company X, I wanted to broaden my experience to other companies".

Most importantly, highlight your value to the new employer. Highlight any big projects you worked on and your contribution. What you lack in formal training you can make up for in experience. Be honest about what you know but do not dismiss your self-education, either.

Comment: +1 for the junior developer positions. This is the same route I'm currently following.

Comment: It depends on country/legal system  a tradional apprentice signs binding papers for a fixed term and once you have finished your looking for a proper full time job.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if there's obvious points about your situation that you see negatively and you're faced with an interview, prepare for questions like this in advance by thinking of ways to phrase your negatives as positively as you can.  For example:  "My last job didn't give me enough experience" is the same as, "I'm interested in gaining more experience, and I think this position will be a great opportunity to do that."

Prospective employers know that you're unhappy with your current situation, or else why would you be looking?  But you can generally try to have a positive attitude towards those downsides, or you can just be very negative about them in general, which will just give the impression that you are a negative person.

Comment: maybe after the apprenticeship they have not offered the OP a Job